# Identifying false alert using python mapreduce

Tags: python, mrjob

Can someone help me regarding the following problem. I am trying to analyze a security log to find false alerts. The false alerts are those containing "TXT was not created" and true are with "txt was not created". How can I extract the particular "txt was not created" from the data source (sample input data given below).

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = unicode(word, "utf-8", errors="ignore") 
        yield word, 1

def reducer(self, key, values):
    yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

A sample input is given here:

```
Mon Feb  1 12:13:59 EST 2016 virtual user etransactiondev started to upload file 
/export/home/pub/etransactiondev/uploads/etransactionenvironment/ABC/rrd/in/WCWT.SMR.XYZ0002.PLSE.INPUT01.LFEP_APOL_D_M_20160201171358.TXT
/export/home/pub/etransactiondev/uploads/etransactionenvironment/ABC/rrd/in/WCWT.SMR.XYZ0002.PLSE.INPUT01.LFEP_APOL_D_M_20160201171358.txt was not created
```

Comment: > "TXT was not created" and true are with "txt was not created". 

Is there an error or is the difference really just the case of the words 'TXT' and 'txt'?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check the first word?

```
word = word.split(' ')
if word[0] == 'TXT':
    do something...
```

Comment: Thanks Vomit for the answer. As of now i am trying to extract username from the input file. Could you help me with extraction of username like in the input line: Mon Feb  1 12:13:59 EST 2016 virtual user etransactiondev started to upload file. I need to extract etransactiondev